# Close App (logout) once a warning message show

Tags: c#, winforms

I use the below C# code to logout user from app. The message show then, after clicking on 'Ok' button in that message, it logout from the app and show the login form.
I need to log out the user and show the login form in the same time the message is shown. So, when the message is shown, the user will be logged out and automatically see the login form without waiting him to click 'ok' in the warning message.

The code I use is as below:

```
    catch
    {
        var loginForm = new LoginForm();
        loginForm.buttonRegister.Visible = false;
        loginForm.textBoxEmail.Text = Email;
        loginForm.textBoxEmail.ReadOnly = true;
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Signed in session has expired, please log back in.", "Google Places Miner");
            loginForm.ShowDialog();
        } catch { }

        if (loginForm.DialogResult != DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Close();
            return;
        }
        CognitoUser = loginForm.CognitoUser;
        AuthResponse = loginForm.AuthResponse;
    }
    finally
    {
        AuthRefreshTimer.Start();
    }
}

private void Google_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
}
```

Comment: Can't you just log them out and then show the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your LoginForm, provide another constructor option:

```
string showMessage = string.Empty;

public LoginForm(string warningMessage)  {
  InitializeComponent();
  showMessage = warningMessage;
}
```

and then in the OnShown override, display the message:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnShown(e);
  if (showMessage != string.Empty) {
    MessageBox.Show(showMessage, ...);
  }
}
```

In your time out block, you would use it:

```
var loginForm = new LoginForm("Signed in session has expired...");
```

Note: Do avoid empty Try-Catches blocks.  It is probably hiding issues with your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely hard to say with any certainty since we don't know what else happens in your app and how the flow goes, but as Jacob Huckins suggested in the comments, why can't you simply change the order?

```
catch
{        
    CognitoUser = loginForm.CognitoUser;
    AuthResponse = loginForm.AuthResponse;
    this.Close();
}
finally
{
    AuthRefreshTimer.Start();
    
    var loginForm = new LoginForm();
    loginForm.buttonRegister.Visible = false;
    loginForm.textBoxEmail.Text = Email;
    loginForm.textBoxEmail.ReadOnly = true;
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Signed in session has expired, please log back in.", "Google Places Miner");
        loginForm.ShowDialog();
    } catch { }
}
```

Comment: ...and those errors might be?  How can we help you if we don't know what's going on?

Comment: Errors of this type
Error CS0106 The modifier 'private' is not valid for this item
Error CS0136 A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope 
Error CS0103 The name 'loginForm' does not exist in the current context
Error CS1061 'Google' does not contain a definition for 'key_TextChanged' and no accessible extension method 'key_TextChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'Google' could be found